# Several closure operations for regular languages

Tags: regular-languages

> Assuming that $L_a$ is a regular language and $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, prove that the following languages are regular:
>
> $$L_1 = \{u \mid \exists v\in\Sigma^* \, uv \in L_a\}$$
>
> $$L_2 = \{w \in \Sigma^* \mid \exists x \in L_a \, n_0(w) = n_0(x) \}$$
>
> $$L_3 = \{uv \mid  u \in L_a \text{ and } v \notin L_a^{R}\}$$
>
> where $n_0(w)$ is the number of zeroes in $w$.

Comment: Your definitions were a bit hard to parse. Hope I guessed correctly.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.  Please ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Sigma' = \{\sigma' \mid \sigma \in \Sigma\}$ be a copy of $\Sigma$. Let $e\colon (\Sigma \cup \Sigma')^* \to \Sigma^*$ be the homomorphism that erases the tags, and let $d\colon (\Sigma \cup \Sigma')^* \to \Sigma^*$ be the homomorphism that deletes all tagged letters. Then $$ L_1 = d(e^{-1}(L_a) \cap \Sigma^* (\Sigma^{\prime*})).$$

Let $d_1\colon \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ be the homomorphism that deletes all $1$s. Then $$ L_2 = d_1^{-1}(d_1(L_a)). $$

Finally, $$ L_3 = L_a \overline{L_a^R}. $$